# Why is the limit of this graph not 4.3?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I just took an online exam as part of a Precalculus course, and one of the problems on my test was as follows:

> Estimate $\lim \limits_{x \to 2} f(x)$ from the graph below.
>
> [image: The graph]

The available answers were:

- $2.8$
- $2$
- $4.3$
- $2.5$

I chose $4.3$ because (at least to me) the line is clearly approaching a $y$-value that is greater than $4$, and no other answer is even close. I was marked as incorrect and lost grade-points. The *correct* answer was not revealed to me.

Considering I didn't miss a single other limits question, I feel that perhaps I was graded incorrectly. That said, I don't want to miss anything, so if someone could enlighten me on this, that would be great.

<sub>P.S. I hope this isn't to localized, but I don't really have any other good options where to post it. :(</sub>

Comment: the line of the graph at $x=2$ is just a bit over the line of the grid marked with 2.5...

Comment: I don't see a single point on the graph with $y$-coordinate more than $3$... Why do you say $4$?

Comment: I do not see a limit here.  It looks like "Estimate $f(2)$ from the graph"

Comment: *facepalm* I just realized my mistake: I didn't see the units of measurement. My eyes somehow glazed over them, and I assumed everything was in the scale of 1. Well, I guess it's true what they say about assuming: It makes an _ass_ out of _U_ and _me_...well, just me, but thanks for clearing that up everyone!

Comment: @Henry: Nonetheless, $f(2)=\lim_{x\to2} f(x)$, provided $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=2$. Perhaps this is part of the exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each box on your grid is given a length of $0.5$ units, you probably thought it was $1$ unit. See that $2.5$?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I'm an idiot, and I payed the price... :(

Comment: @Miguel: Not an idiot... just a gaga, like most of us. :D

Answer (score 3):

Note that the units of measure used in the two axes are the same. In particular, near $x=2$, the curve is slightly higher than $y=2.5$, hence the answer is $2.8$.

Answer (score 3):

Look closely at the scale. $Y$ is defined as 2.5 for 5 units. Hence the answer should be 2.8